# Transfer onedrive business folder to another user in the organization

Tags: permissions, onedrive

We have a user named `tmadeup@onmicrosoft.conglomo.com` he is currently housing all the folders everyone uses in one drive like the `SpongeBob`, `rock's modern life`, and `ah real monsters` folders; meaning. He shares them out to everyone in the office.

They now made a new Microsoft account called `robotjones@onmicrosoft.conglomo.com`. They want to transfer all the actual folders into `robotjones` account and then share the folders from there with the same permissions.

Is there a way to do this all through the web? We know how to give ownership but the folder still exists on `tmadeup` account as the actual source which is what they don't want.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: The owner of the files should be able to cut and paste the files from one root folder to another.  I assume both accounts are not using the same root folder?

Answer (score 0):

I figured the best way to do this was to instead use SharePoint and host the files from there with the correct permissions. This helped my situation but if someone has a more direct answer let me know.

Comment: Yeah; Sharing it the way you were was probably fine for a few dozen files.  SharePoint allows everyone to own the file as it were.

Comment: OneDrive is like a personal SharePoint site, in my opinion, using SharePoint is a good way. Here is an article I move here, "[Transfer all OneDrive files to another user via PowerShell](https://gcits.com/knowledge-base/transfer-users-onedrive-files-another-user-via-powershell/)".